# Is there way to cap memory usage and/or CPU affinity globally (on boot) to allow manual exceptions per instance in the Windows NT kernel?

Tags: virtualization, kernel, sandbox

I don’t know if this is even possible in Windows. But I know it can be done with Linux. Can it be done in Sindows?

As in...

- tricking Windows into running boot up on 1 NUMA domain/CCX
- Or 32G of Ram instead of 64G

But be able to manually assign resources per instance.

I’m trying to find a way to dedicate cores, threads and a spot of RAM directly to processes. Absolute scheduling for sandboxing/Virt/etc.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible on Windows

Comment: is it possible per application?

Comment: You can set the affinity of a processor through Task Manager, beyond that, you will have no control over how Windows manages the resource for a specific process

Comment: so you can set the affinity through task manager